# Error in delete query using asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, ado.net

i trying delete some rows using GridViews.

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["ID_Oosby"] = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;



        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RentCarConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn1.Open();
            string deleteQuery = "Delete From from Klienci Where IDOsoby = @idosoby ";
            SqlCommand com2 = new SqlCommand(deleteQuery, conn1);
            com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idosoby", Session["ID_Osoby"]);
            com2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn1.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Nie udąło sie usunac uzytkownika" + ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

But when i execute it I receive error message

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'. w System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: You have two FROM clauses in the sql statement. Get rid of one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change sql query to:

```
string deleteQuery = "Delete From Klienci Where IDOsoby = @idosoby ";
```

You have two FROM clauses causing the exception.